# Computer I/O Button on a Wall Plate

Tags: electrical, walls, low-voltage

I am looking to put a computer monitor in my kitchen and the actual computer in my basement.  I want to install a wall plate in my kitchen with a button that can turn the computer on and off.

Basically I need a wall plate with a 5v push button that I can wire into the computers motherboard.

Any ideas?

Basically I am looking for something like this:
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B081VGC6VT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081VGC6VT)

Except instead of that button it would be a button in a wall plate.

In the computer this is what I would ultimately plug the switch into:
[image]

The green is the power and the blue is (assuming that the switch is capable) for the LEDs.

Comment: It's possible you can remotely control the PC without wires:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/pc-remote/9wzdncrfhvwt#activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: Hahahah, @SteveWellens. From your link, `Windows XP, Vista, Windows 7, or Windows 8
`. LOL, it's only supported by EOL'd versions of Windows. I'm sure you weren't intentionally recommending out of date software, I just found it amusing. I'm laughing at MS, not you...

Comment: @SteveWellens - the whole point is to be able to turn the computer on/off WITH wires.  That link doesn't help me at all.

Comment: You could certainly mount that button _to_ a wall plate. Just use double sided tape to stick it to the outside of a blank plate then screw the plate to the wall. Or, if you only want access to the button, drill a hole through the blank plate, file it square to fit the button nicely, and epoxy the button to the inside of the plate.

Comment: However, this basically boils down to being a shopping question now that you've explained yourself further. "I want a product like this but different in that way." You're now asking us to do your internet searching for you, and that's off topic. :/

Comment: I assume you are going to be running USB and HDMI as well?  You could easily just get the button you linked and use a Cable Access Brush Wall Plate.  Just keep in mind the limitations on USB length being about 15ft.  I have a Kasa Smart Outlet on mine with the bios set to turn on when power is restored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably already aware that PC power buttons work by shorting 2 pins on the case header (which is actually shorting 2 contacts on the 24-pin ATX power header). It's trivial to connect to these pins, or solder into the case button wires so that the case power button still works.

So I'm guessing what you're looking (shopping) for is the wall-installable button itself. The type of button used on PC cases is "normally-open momentary switch" and you can find these in a variety of styles, including [Decora-type paddle switches](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001H1EP7K) that may fit with your existing light switch/outlet style, or [arcade-type buttons](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079HR5Q4R) if you're looking for a similar aesthetic. As others have suggested, any type of wire will do since this is very low voltage, but common types like Cat5/5e/6 or thermostat/doorbell wire would be great.

However, I would also like to bring your attention to a device called Switchbot; this is a smarthome device that "pushes a button" when activated and can be configured to push a button based on any trigger (timer, a click in an app, a script or web event, etc). Rather than replacing or modifying hardware, Switchbot devices mount on the surface of your hardware and give you an instant smart upgrade. You could, for example, install Switchbot so that the button presses the power button on the PC downstairs, then link that to a script, phone app, or timer so it presses the power button whenever you need it to.

(I am not affiliated with Switchbot in any way, I just think they're interesting and applicable to this problem)

Comment: You are going in the right direct!  The term "Open Momentary Switch" was what I was looking for (I just wasn't sure what to search for).  I found a few hits but they look pretty off-brand - are there any brands you have used in the past?  Ideally I would find something where at least the wall plate would match others.

Comment: I edited a couple examples in; you can get these at your local home improvement store also. Any button can be added into (or glued onto) a blank wall plate so that it matches your kitchen decor.

Answer (score 3):

Simple low-voltage wiring project.

A low voltage box or ring (or a normal junction box is fine, just don't put any line voltage stuff in it), a blank cover plate you put a hole suited to your pushbutton in, and some low voltage in-wall wire (Cat5e riser or plenum being the most easily available at my house "known good for the use", but thermostat or doorbell wire would also qualify and be easy enough to get.) Your choice as to whether you use a box or ring with a cable-pass-through port faceplate or a faceplate with some sort of connector on the basement end of this setup. Depending how unfinished that end is, I guess you could just run the wire into the computer without a box in an unfinished basement, too. I'd put a box there for the sake of being tidy ("in a workmanlike manner") about it.

Comment: Do you have any examples of specific products that might work?  I'm trying to figure out what to search for.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to get one of the plastic [wall plates that has a round hole in the middle](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Hubbell-1-Gang-Ivory-Single-Round-Midsize-Wall-Plate/1000050097) (typically seen with a coax TV cable running out of it), and then find a button the same size as the hole.  You're looking for a normally-open (N.O.), momentary-on switch - sometimes labeled as "OFF-(ON)".

The opening in that particular plate is 0.4".  [This button](https://www.jameco.com/z/40-1665-01-Judco-Manufacturing-Push-Button-Switch-Miniature-Single-Pole-Single-Throw-OFF-Momentary-ON-5-Inch-Wire-14-VDC-4-Amp-3-8-Inch-Mounting_22218.html) would fit that hole, but has a bulky back end that might be hard to fit in a wall box.  A button like [this one](https://www.jameco.com/z/66-2412-Jameco-Valuepro-SPST-OFF-ON-Pushbutton-Switch-Round-Plunger-3A-125-VAC_2231865.html) would be easier to work with and is smaller than the opening but since it locks on with a hex nut, you can add some thin washers to fill the gap.  Lots of [buttons](https://www.jameco.com/z/R13-502-3A-M-A-Jameco-Valuepro-Momentary-Pushbutton-Switch-SPST-OFF-Momentary-ON-3A-125VAC-1-5A-250VAC_2274431.html) are available at or just under 0.5"; you may be able to use one of them if you can enlarge the hole a bit with a file.  Both the wall plates and the buttons are available in many different sizes, so find two that match (or are close enough).

This is a low-voltage application so you shouldn't have to worry about exceeding the electrical capability of the switch - most are designed for significantly higher loads.  [Alarm system wire](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Southwire-1-ft-22-4-Solid-White-Security-Cable/4284059) should suffice for the wiring.  It's got two conductors plus an outer jacket, it's designed to be run through walls, and it's easy to find.  Solder it to the button terminals and protect with heat shrink tubing.  Run the wire through your wall alongside your video cable - stay away from anything running full-voltage power.  On the basement side, you can terminate the cable to a [wall plate designed for speaker systems](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-White-2-Gang-Audio-Wall-Plate-1-Pack-2-banana-wh/203715825).  That will give you two  binding posts that are designed to connect to bare wires.  Take your computer's existing power button+cable, cut off the button, and connect the wires to the binding posts.  Most importantly, label the backside of both of these wall plates as to what they do and are connected to.  This is definitely *not* a typical use case, and is likely to confuse future owners if you don't document what this circuit does.

Answer (score 0):

There are a wide variety of Arduino/RaspberryPi/etc low power, small form factor system on a chip type of solutions that would probably work quite well for you in this situation. If you're knowledgeable enough to "wire into the computer's motherboard" to get a remote power switch, you've probably got the chops to set up something like that. As a bonus, they're pretty much dirt cheap!

I *just* (this week!) got a couple of WeMos D1 - there are button & relay modules that would most likely do the job. I envision two modules - one with a button in the kitchen and one with a relay in the basement. WiFi communication between the two sends "button pushed" from the kitchen to the basement where the software then says "close relay" or "open relay".

Comment: There are off-the-shelf smart devices that already include relays and can do up to line voltage (120VAC) if you don't want to tinker with your own microcontroller/firmware/relay configuration. Check out Shelly and Sonoff for 2 popular examples.

Comment: Very true, @FredricShope, but (having just gotten into this world, as I mentioned) roll-your-own is _seriously_ cheaper than buying prebuilt, and if OP is comfortable connecting non-standard things to his MoBo, he'll certainly have no issues with this.

Comment: @FreeMan - that is definitely overthinking it - I have updated the description a bit to show explain more.

Comment: _wonders what the down vote was about..._